# Browser Router (React app ) on Github not working

Tags: reactjs, github, browser, react-router, react-router-dom

i have a little React app project and i have deployed it in Github. It works, even i am using import { BrowserRouter, Link, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom"; to routing and works ... for my home component but not for the rest. This is my code: `class App extends React.Component {

render() {

```
 return <div>
   <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
       <Switch>
          <Route exact path ="/" component={Show} />
          <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
       </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>

  </div>
```

}

}
export default App;`

I have used this in local machine without the "basename" and worked. Now, in the github server my problem is that it is currently showing my first component when you visit my app main url but is not working for the other component, "/contact". I am not sure if i have to use the '<Link to ' property. Anyway, i just want to know why is working for my main url path (https://namegithub.github.io/main-path/) but not for any other path (https://namegithub.github.io/main-path/contact).

Sorry is a dummy question but actually i am just giving my first steps in React.

Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, we can't use BrowserRouter in git hub because github does not support browser history. So instead we can use HashRouter and this uses the hash portion of the url to keep the UI in sync with the URL. So, my code now is: 
 <HashRouter basename="/personal-site">
           
              <Route exact path ="/" component={Show} />
              <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
           
       </HashRouter>
And it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can you this code

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route} from 'react-router-dom'
return <div>
   <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
       <Switch>
          <Route exact path ="/" component={Show} />
          <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
       </Switch>
   </Router>

  </div>
```